# Pebble watch font2png.py, "An Integer is Required" error

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, pebble-watch

[Pebble Github: font2png.py](https://github.com/pebble/pebble-sdk-examples/blob/master/watches/big_time/fonttools/font2png.py)

I am having difficult getting this code to run. I'm attempting to use the font2png.py but it won't work. I run the command

```
python fonttools/font2png.py
```

and I keep getting these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fonttools/font2png.py", line 92, in <module>
    tile_image.save(OUTPUT_IMAGE_FILEPATH_TEMPLATE % digit)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1439, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py", line 572, in _save
    ImageFile._save(im, _idat(fp, chunk), [("zip", (0,0)+im.size, 0, rawmode)])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 481, in _save
    e = Image._getencoder(im.mode, e, a, im.encoderconfig)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 399, in _getencoder
    return apply(encoder, (mode,) + args + extra)
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Any ideas? I have the fonts in the correct path and everything. I'm using Roboto-Condensed.ttf if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 python -m pdb font2png.py
```

Then use interactive debugger to poke around data to see whynit crashes.

Then file a bug and/or a patch on the project on Github.